# How to use sed to fix an xml issue

Tags: regex, xml, sed

I have an xml with the following (invalid) structure

```
<tag1>text1<tag2>text2</tag1><tag3>text3</tag3><tag1></tag2>text4</tag1>
```

I want to use sed to change it into

```
<tag1>text1<tag2>text2<tag3>text3</tag3></tag2>text4</tag1>
```

i.e. I want to remove `</tag1>...<tag1>` (and move everything in between under the enclosing `tag1`), if I encounter an invalid xml substring as `<tag1></*`

I have tried using sed without success (one such attempt is below)

```
sed -e 's/<\/tag1>\(.*\)<tag1><\//\1<\//g'
```

It does work with the example above, but if I have two occurrence of the same condition it just removes the first `</tag1>` and the last `<tag1>` instead of performing the replacement twice

```
echo '<tag1>text1<tag2>text2</tag1><tag3>text3</tag3><tag1></tag2>text4</tag1><tag1>text5<tag4>text6</tag1><tag3>text7</tag3><tag1></tag4>text8</tag1>' | sed -e 's/<\/tag1>\(.*\)<tag1><\//\1<\//g'
```

outputs

```
<tag1>text1<tag2>text2<tag3>text3</tag3><tag1></tag2>text4</tag1><tag1>text5<tag4>text6</tag1><tag3>text7</tag3></tag4>text8</tag1>
```

I think sed just expands the RE to cover the largest selection, but what should I do if I do not want it to do such thing ?

Comment: Let me ask my question differently, can the following algorithm be implemented in sed ? 1. Search for `<tag1></` 2. Search backward for the first `</tag1>` 3. Remove `</tag1>` and `<tag1>` from the text in between

Comment: Y'know, the correct solution would be to fix the process that produces the invalid XML.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the luxury I could have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want non-greedy matching, but to the best of my knowledge, sed doesn't support it. Can you use perl or do you have to use sed?

Try: `perl -p -e 's/<\/tag1>(.*?)<tag1>(\<\/.+?<\/tag1>)/\1\2/g'`

I think the issue is that the regex has to match through to the end of the actual closing  or else that closing tag becomes the beginning of the next match.

Comment: perl is fine too, I actually did not know that feature is called non-greedy matching, adding that into my internet search keywords, I think I am getting close. I will have to find the proper perl syntax but at least the following did not work `perl -pe 's|</tag1>(.*?)<tag1></|\1</|g'`

Comment: @JohnBrown - I updated my answer. Give that a shot and if it's not what you are looking for, then give me some more detail.

Comment: @JohnBrown - One other thing. I don't think you have the same condition twice in your second pattern. Here is the start of the second set of "bad tags" </tag1><tag3>text7</tag3></tag2>text8</tag1>, there is no <tag1> for the regex to find and close the pattern.

Comment: Your suggestion is exactly as what I put in my comment above and neither worked (due to perl syntax maybe ?). But you do have a point that the condition for the second set of bad tags is a little bit different and the original substitution may not work as expected when applied to the second set

Comment: @JohnBrown Please note that in my command, I escaped the < and > as well.

Comment: I know, this is the output that I am getting
`<tag1>text1<tag2>text2<tag3>text3</tag3></tag2>text4<tag1>text5<tag4>text6</tag1><tag3>text7</tag3></tag4>text8</tag1>`, the correct one should be
`<tag1>text1<tag2>text2<tag3>text3</tag3></tag2>text4</tag1><tag1>text5<tag4>text6<tag3>text7</tag3></tag4>text8</tag1>`

Comment: Yes, I wanted to emphasize that the invalid broken tag can be something other than tag2 as well, but even with the original example the solution does not work, and I think it has something to do with the </tag1><tag1> in the middle of the example string as you previously suggested

Comment: @JohnBrown - I've updated the answer. Can you give it a try?

Comment: it works as I expected, thank you very much for the help. Initially I was trying to use sed labels/conditional branches to do it and was hoping to learn something new from the community (see my comment to the original message about the algorithm that I had in mind), but in any case, I accept your answer to my question. I still could use your expertise if you have a solution using conditional branches in sed.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's|</tag1><tag3>|<tag3>|;s|</tag3><tag1>|</tag3>|' file.xml
```

Output:

```
<tag1>text1<tag2>text2<tag3>text3</tag3></tag2>text4</tag1>
```

Comment: I used a short example, tag3 is not known beforehand, there maybe additional text and/or tags between `</tag1>` and `<tag3>`, this solution does not work

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/<tag1>/\n/g;s/<\/tag1>(<tag3>[^\n]*)\n/\1/g;s/\n/<tag1>/g' file
```

Reduce `<tag1>` to a unique character i.e `\n` then use the negated character class `[^\n]` to obtain non-greedy matching. Following the changes reverse the initial substitution.

Comment: This solution does work with the example that I provided, but my source also has \n and this could corrupt other parts, although I think this concept can be helpful in my situation as a last resort, I still hope I could learn something new by a solution using labels/branches in sed

Comment: As sed is line based unless you introduce newlines by the means of `N` ,`G` , `H` and the `s/../../` commands, newlines cannot be present in your source. Perhaps you could detail where this happens and provide a better example.

Comment: @protong, you are correct about newlines, I really liked your approach of breaking the complex string into smaller pieces to avoid dealing with greedy/non-greedy selections. The reason that I am not accepting your answer is that it has tag3 in the RE section, the actual XML that I am processing is very complex and the only known information is tag1 and the fact that it is breaking another tag, the rest of the structure can change arbitrarily. I am pretty sure that one can come up with a similar RE that is not dependent to anything other than tag1 though.

Comment: Here is another solution using potong's approach, the greedy behavior actually works to my advantage to find the last `</tag1>`, `sed -e 's|<tag1></|\n</|g;s|\([^\n]*\)</tag1>\([^\n]*\)\n|\1\2|g'`

Answer (score 0):

GNU sed

```
sed '\,<tag1></,{ s,</tag1>,,; s,<tag1>,,2; }' <<END
<tag1>text1<tag2>text2</tag1><tag3>text3</tag3><tag1></tag2>text4</tag1>  <!-- error case -->
<tag1><tag2 /></tag1><tag1><tag3 /></tag1>                                <!-- should not change -->
END
```

```
<tag1>text1<tag2>text2<tag3>text3</tag3></tag2>text4</tag1>  <!-- error case -->
<tag1><tag2 /></tag1><tag1><tag3 /></tag1>                                <!-- should not change -->
```

If the string `<tag1></` is seen, then remove the first `</tag1>` and the second `<tag1>`

Comment: This solution does not work if the condition happens a couple of times in the same line and it is a bit dangerous as it may remove tag1's that are properly instantiated